# Sharepoint - How to get image(s) from a RichTextField?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Hi
how can i get the image(s) inserted inside a RichTextField in order to test the weight of the image ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are going to use this c# code?

Comment: At the creation of a publishing page ... the purpose is to verify the weight of the image(s) so the contributor can't create a page if the weight of the image(s) inserted inside a richtextfield is too large.

Comment: The image is inserted after creating the page right? Then how will you get  the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the image in the RichTextField? Is it not the a link to an image?

Then you need to parse the the html in the rich text field, select all the image links and then check the size of the images.